# React setState and await

Tags: reactjs, async-await, setstate

While the functional setState() is recommended when the current state is being used, the function still cannot be async. How could we develop a function that uses the state, calls a REST API and changes the state right after?

This is the original function, that disregards the async behavior of setState.

```
onSortColumnChanged = (sortColumn) => async (event) => {
    const prev = this.state;
​    const searchParams = { ...prev.params, sortColumn: sortColumn };
​    const result = await this.callSearch(searchParams);
​    this.setState({ params: searchParams, result: result });
}
```

If we change the above function to use functional setState, VSCode complains that await can only be used in async functions.

```
onSortColumnChanged = (sortColumn) => (event) => {
    this.setState((prev) => {
​        const searchParams = { ...prev.params, sortColumn: sortColumn };
​        const result = await this.callSearch(searchParams);
​        return { params: searchParams, result: result };
    });
}
```

I think I'm missing something fundamental here.

Comment: I think you just need to change `this.setState((prev) => {` to `this.setState(async (prev) => {`

Comment: @Tony `setState` won't resolve promises

Answer (score 3):

### Short answer

```
onSortColumnChanged = (sortColumn) => async (event) => {
    const searchParams = { ...this.state.params, sortColumn: sortColumn };
    const result = await this.callSearch(searchParams);
    this.setState(prev => {
        prev.params.sortColumn = sortColumn
        prev.result = result
        return prev
    })
}
```

### Long answer

#### Why use setState callbacks

[The React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) state that multiple calls to setState may be batched together.

Let's pretend you have a chat app. You might have a function that looks like this:

```
async incoming_message(message){
    this.setState({messages: this.state.messages.concat(message)})
}
```

So if 2 messages come in a few milliseconds apart, React may batch these two calls to `setState()`

```
this.setState({messages: [].concat(message_1)}) // 1
this.setState({messages: [].concat(message_2)}) // 2
```

and when `2` runs, we will lose `message_1`.

Providing setState with a transform function is the solution

```
async incoming_message(message){
    this.setState(prev => {
        prev.messages.push(message)
        return prev
    })
}
```

In the callback-based setState, the 1st message will not be lost, since instead of specifying an exact state to write, we specify a way to transform the old state into the new state.

#### Important notes

The object version of `setState()` does a shallow merge of the new state and the previous state. This means that calling `setState()` with an object will **only** update the keys that you pass in.

If you choose to use the callback version of `setState()` instead, you are expected to return the **entire** new state. So when you have

```
return { params: searchParams, result: result };
```

in your `setState()` callback, you will lose all state value except `params` and `result`.

#### Your code

> the functional setState() is recommended when the current state is being used

It is important to understand *why* the functional `setState()` is recommended. If your code will not break when multiple `setState()` calls are batched together, it is OK to pass an object instead of a function.

If you still want to use the callback pattern, you don't need to do all the work in your `setState()` callback, you only need to specify how to transform the old state into the new one.

```
onSortColumnChanged = (sortColumn) => async (event) => {
    const {params} = this.state;
    const searchParams = { ...params, sortColumn: sortColumn };
    const result = await this.callSearch(searchParams);
    this.setState(prev => {
        // prev is the old state
        // we changed sortColumn param
        prev.params.sortColumn = sortColumn
        // and we changed the result
        prev.result = result
        // and we return the new, valid state
        return prev

        // or if you prefer an immutable approach
        return Object.assign({}, prev, {
            params: {...prev.params, sortColumn: sortColumn},
            result: result,
        }) 
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the complete explanation. I still have one question though. The search params could be changed by other handlers, `this.state.params.filters` could be changed by `onFilterChanged`, for instance. Using your last code, when `const {params} = this.state` is executed we could receive outdated filters, hence the search will not provide accurate results. Assuming that the implementation of `onFilterChanged` is similar, we may end up either with results of a wrong filter or a wrong sort column.

Comment: @GabrielaVasselai `const {params}` was confusing and there were some other bugs I just fixed.

Comment: @GabrielaVasselai @GabrielaVasselai If we used `params` in the `setState` callback, we could possibly create incorrect state. However, the `setState` callback *only* modifies `state.result` and `state.params.searchParams`, so `state.filters` will be safe if it is modified somewhere else in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

Think of 'await' as a callback function of promise. So you don't have promise here and you are calling callback function. Hence, VSCode ask you to add the promise which in this case it is 'async' function.