# Is this okay to set await on set state in react class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-table

Hi I am new to react and I am implementing `react-table`. I know react automatically renders the component if any of the props changes. Right now for my jobs table I am trying to hide and show filters on columns based on checkbox. `react-table` already gives a `filterable` option to do this. But I don't want to show a filter to my `actions` column.

Here

```
class JobsTable extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      isFilterable: true,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getJobs();
  }


  getFormattedDate(dateString) {
    const current_datetime = new Date(dateString);
    const formatted_date =
      ('0' + current_datetime.getDate()).slice(-2) +
      '/' +
      ('0' + (current_datetime.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) +
      '/' +
      current_datetime.getFullYear();
    return formatted_date;
  }

  getJobs = async pageIndex => {
    pageIndex = pageIndex || 1;
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });

    const { recordsToFetch } = this.state;
    const resp = await getAllJobs(pageIndex, recordsToFetch);

    if (resp.success) {
      this.setState({
        data: resp.data.jobs,
        pages: Math.ceil(resp.data.totalRecords / recordsToFetch),
        isLoading: false,
        showPagination: resp.data.jobs.length > 0,
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({ data: [], isLoading: false, showPagination: false });
    }
    ReactTooltip.rebuild();
  };

  getCell(row) {
    let value = row.value !== undefined && row.value !== null ? row.value : '';
    if (row.column.Header === 'Submitted') {
      value = this.getFormattedDate(value);
    }
    if (row.column.Header === 'Problem Summary') {
      value = Array.isArray(value) ? value.join('. ') : value;
    }
    if (row.column.Header === 'Quotes') {
      value = JSON.stringify(value);
    }
    if (row.column.Header === 'Actions') {
      return (
        <>
          <div
            id="view"
            className="react-table-cell-style"
            style={{ display: 'inline', cursor: 'pointer' }}>
            {' '}
            <a
              rel="noopener noreferrer"
              target="_blank"
              href={`/job/${row.original.userId}/${row.original.jobId}`}>
              View
            </a>
          </div>{' '}
          <div
            id="edit"
            className="react-table-cell-style"
            style={{ display: 'inline', cursor: 'pointer' }}>
            | Edit
          </div>{' '}
          <div
            id="viewQuote"
            style={{ display: 'inline', cursor: 'pointer' }}
            className="react-table-cell-style">
            {value > 0 && `| Quote${value > 1 ? 's' : ''}`}
          </div>
        </>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div data-tip={row.column.Header + ' : ' + value} className="react-table-cell-style">
        <span>{value}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }

  getHeader(headerName, valueAccessor, sortable = true) {
    const { isFilterable } = this.state;
    const headerClassName = 'react-table-header';
    return {
      headerClassName: headerClassName,
      Header: headerName,
      accessor: valueAccessor,
      Cell: row => this.getCell(row),
      filterable: headerName === 'Actions' ? false : isFilterable,
      sortable: sortable,
      width: headerName === 'Actions' ? 140 : undefined,
    };
  }


  render() {
    let jobColumns = [
      this.getHeader('Job ID', 'jobId'),
      this.getHeader('User ID', 'userId'),
      this.getHeader('Name', 'name'),
      this.getHeader('Email', 'email'),
      this.getHeader('Submitted', 'submitted'),
      this.getHeader('Status', 'status'),
      this.getHeader('Phone Number', 'number'),
      this.getHeader('Device', 'device'),
      this.getHeader('Make', 'make'),
      this.getHeader('Model', 'model'),
      this.getHeader('Problem Summary', 'problemSummary'),
      this.getHeader('Anything else?', 'anythingElse'),
      this.getHeader('Postcode', 'postcode'),
      this.getHeader("T's Matched", 'techspertMatchedCount'),
      this.getHeader('Not Available', 'techspertNotAvailable'),
      this.getHeader('Quotes', 'quotesCount'),
      this.getHeader('Viewed Quote', 'viewedQuote'),
      this.getHeader('Chatted with T', 'isChatted'),
      this.getHeader('Got to Payment', 'gotToPayment'),
      this.getHeader('Actions', 'quotesCount', false),
    ];

    const {
      data,
      isFilterable,
    } = this.state;


    const setFilters = async () => {
      const { isFilterable } = this.state;
      await this.setState({ isFilterable: !isFilterable });
      this.getJobs();
    };

    return (
      <div className="jobsTable-Container">
        <div className="jobsTable_show-filter">
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            onChange={setFilters}
            checked={isFilterable}
            value={isFilterable}
          />
          Show Filters
        </div>
          <ReactTable
            data={data}
            columns={jobColumns}
            filterable
          />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default JobsTable;
```

The question which I want to raise is, Is this okay to use `await` in `setFilters` methood. Because if i dont do this and call the `getJobs` methood, the old values are not updated. So is this Okay?

Comment: no u dont do await in setState

Comment: It is "okay", but not certainly useful.

Comment: here's how you use `await` in general .... does it return a Promise? if not, then don't bother

Comment: The await operator is used to wait for a **Promise**. It can **only** be used **inside an async** function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

So, it won't work as you can expect and there is no reason to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React setState and await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49216135/react-setstate-and-await)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem here is that `getJobs` relies on the state being up to date, but as state updates are asynchronous, the update happens *after* the `getJobs` call. By adding `await`, you defer the `getJobs` call to a microtask. That might (or might not!) be after the state update:

```
  ------------- time ---------->
  setState -------> state update
          await --------> getJobs
```

So your "fix" is problematic. Instead use the second parameter of `setState`, which get definetly called after the state update:

```
 this.setState({ isFilterable: !isFilterable }, () => this.getJobs());
```

Or even better, not rely on the current state:

```
 this.setState(({ isFilterable }) => ({ isFilterable: !isFilterable }), () => this.getJobs());
```

That turns the diagram above into:

```
  setState -> state update -> getJobs
```

Comment: Oh thanks. I did not know this we can write something like this  () => this.getJobs() in set state too

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using await in combination with setState, I think what you are looking for would be something like this.

```
this.setState({ 
    isFilterable: !isFilterable 
}, () => {
    this.getJobs()
});
```